# How can I force the optimizer to use hash join in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

In SQL Server, it is `select * from A inner hash join B on A.a = B.b`. Does PostgreSQL have similar join hint?

Comment: Why do you want to force it to use a HASH join? Is a query slow? What does the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` plan look like?

Comment: No. It's just a general question. I need to force the join operator type and join order for some research purposes.

Comment: You could try disabling all of the enable_* settings except for `enable_hashjoin = on`.

Comment: I am afraid no way! Just as bma said , You could try disabling all of the enable_* settings except for enable_hashjoin = on